# Fetch my own posts from database in news feed only one time

Tags: php

I creared a news feed system so when i extract the posts of the users who following me or i do. i also get multiple posts of me.

Example:

```
#Friends Requests table
#(My ID is : 1)

Id|sender|receiver|statu
----------------------------
1 |1     |2       |accepted
----------------------------
2 |3     |1       |accepted
----------------------------
```

Getting posts code

```
$getFollowers = $PDO->query(" SELECT * FROM friends_requests WHERE (sender='$myID' OR receiver='$myID') AND statu='accepted' ");

while($getFollowersData = $getFollowers->fetch()){

  $getPosts = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE publisherID=".$getFollowersData['sender']." OR publisherID=".$getFollowersData['receiver']);

while($showPosts = $getPosts->fetch()){
//SHOW ALL POSTS
}
}
```

so guys is there any other way to do the same thing but getting my own posts only one time?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple GROUP BY solve your problem? Though I'm not sure how your *posts* table looks, or even storing duplicate posts like this is ideal.

```
$getPosts = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE publisherID=".$getFollowersData['sender']." OR publisherID=".$getFollowersData['receiver']." GROUP BY Id;";
```